# OpenGL using GL_STENCIL with a sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, stencil-buffer

I'm working with OpenGL and I am trying to create a sphere that has a reflective surface. I have it reflecting but the reflection isn't correct. The object in the reflection should be bent and deformed according to the curve of the surface, instead I'm getting only a straight reflection. I haven't used GL_STENCIL much so help would be very much appreciated. I have provided pieces of code such as the creation of the sphere and the draw method. If anyone needs more let me know.

Creation:

```
sphere = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(sphere,  GLU_FILL);
gluQuadricNormals(sphere, GLU_SMOOTH);
gluSphere(sphere, 1, 100, 100);
gluDeleteQuadric(sphere);
```

Drawing:

```
glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1);
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);

glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE); //disable the color mask
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE); //disable the depth mask
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); //enable the stencil testing
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE); //set the stencil buffer to replace our data

sphereDraw(); //the mirror surface

glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE); //enable the color mask
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); //enable the depth mask

glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP); //set the stencil buffer to keep our next lot of data

glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); //flip the reflection vertically
glTranslatef(0,2,-20); //translate the reflection onto the drawing plane
glRotatef(angle,0,1,0); //rotate the reflection
//draw object as our reflection
glPopMatrix();

glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); //disable the stencil testing

glEnable(GL_BLEND); //enable alpha blending
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //set the blending function
sphereDraw(); //draw our bench
glDisable(GL_BLEND); //disable alpha blending

//draw object
```

Since I'm new to using GL_STENCIL I wasn't sure if it's just something small or if much more needs to be done to detect that angle of reflection.

Comment: BTW- your life will probably get easier if the first thing you do is start using shaders. Stencil reflection doesn't "bend" by its nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [reflection/environment mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping)?

There are 2 main forms.  [Spherical environment mapping](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3139/hardware_accelerated_spherical_.php) usually works by having a pre-calculated environment map. It can, however, been done dynamically.  Its main drawback is that it is view dependent.

The other system is [Cubic Environment mapping](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cube_map_ogl_tutorial.html).  Cubic is very easy to set up and involves simply rendering your scene 6 times in 6 different direction (ie on to each face of the cube).  Cubic env mapping is view independent.

There is another system that sits between spherical and cubic.  Its called [dual paraboloid environment mapping](http://www.gamedev.net/columns/hardcore/dualparaboloid/).  It has the draw back that generating the dual paraboloids is quite complex (like spherical) but (like cubic) it is view independent.

Comment: I had already seen the cubic mapping but that seems a bit much. The reason I asked the question is because of a reflections and this <a href="http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=27">NeHe Tutorial</a> but I would rather have mirroring than shadow. Thanks for your comment though, if I take this more in depth it'll be worth exploring.

Comment: @Anthony:  Cubic environment mapping is REALLY easy to do.  Your problem arises from the fact that your reflection system will only work for a flat plane.  Either you use one of the methods above ... or you don't get accurate (ish) reflections.

Comment: @Anthony: Equally shadows are pretty easy and learning cube mapping is dead handy for omni-directional lights.